# In Kotlin, how to set object members in one expression when its created?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, expression, member

If there is no such constructor that could set all the required members, how could I set them in one expression instead of setting them line by line?

```
class Time {
    var hour = 0
    var min = 0
    var sec = 0
}

fun main() {
    val time = Time()
    time.hour = 2
    time.min = 41
    time.sec = 27
}
```

Comment: Apart from the technical how-to-do-in-Kotlin, using some built-in class for time would be recommended, say `java.time.LocalTime` for example...

Answer (score 3):

The scope function `apply{}` can be used:

```
fun main() {
    val time = Time().apply { // `this` keyword can be used to refer the object
        hour = 2 // this.hour also accepted
        min = 41
        sec = 27
    }
}
```

The same expression in one line:

```
val time = Time().apply { hour = 2; min = 41; sec = 27 }
```